# How to Pass a Value from One Activity to Another Activity/Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Iam trying to pass a value my `Cartadapter` to `CartActivity`.

My code is as follows:

**CartActivity.java:**

```
    cartTotalChanged((cartAdapter.getTotal()));
```

**CartAdapter.java:**

```
    public Double getTotal() {
        Double total = 0d;
        try{
            for (MenuItem item : dataList)
                total += item.getTotal();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return total;
        }
        finally{
            return total;
        }


    }
```

**cartTotalChanged Function:**

```
 public void cartTotalChanged(Double totalAmount) {
        if (coupon != null) {
            totalAmount = totalAmount - (coupon.getType().equals("fixed") ? coupon.getReward() : ((totalAmount * coupon.getReward()) / 100));
        }
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
        subtotal.setText(decimalFormat.format(totalAmount) + currency);
        double sc = (totalAmount * serviceCharge / 100);
        feeService.setText(decimalFormat.format(sc) + currency);
        total.setText(decimalFormat.format(totalAmount > 0 ? (totalAmount + sc + deliveryFee) : 0) + currency);
        Helper.setCart(sharedPreferenceUtil, cartItems);
    }
```

My problem here is  `cartTotalChanged((cartAdapter.getTotal()));` is returning a `Null` and My app crashed with multiple thread failure.

kindly help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: can you show the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

To pass data  from  adapter to activity use following way:

1.use **Interface** to create new interface class.

2.In activity implement that interface class and override passing data method.

3.In adapter class assign variable as inside parameter to interface method

**Interface class:**

```
Class Ainterface
{ 
public void passData(String setData);
 }
```

**Adapterclass:**

```
  Ainterface ainterface;
  Adapterclass(Context context)
    {
     ainterface=context;
    }

    /*add below line in your onbind or onclick... whenever you want to pass data from adpter to activity use below line*/
    ainterface.passData("set your variable which is load to activity");
```

**Activity class:**

```
Class MainActivity implements Ainterface
{

/*inside onCreate */
AdapterClass ac=new AdapterClass(this);
public void passData(String getdata)
{
Log.v("String is",getdata);
/*do something*/
}
}
```

i hope its work on you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like below:

```
public class Globals{
private static Globals instance;

// Global variable

private Double cartTotal;


// Restrict the constructor from being instantiated
private Globals(){}

public void setData(Double d){
    this.cartTotal=d;
}
public Double getData(){
    return this.cartTotal;
}

public static synchronized Globals getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
        instance=new Globals();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

Then on your adapter set it like this:

```
Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
g.setData(cartTotal);
```

And receive in your Activity as:

```
Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
Double cartTotal = g.getData();
```

You can set a number of Global variables like this as per your requirement.

Hope this helps !!